# Excel vba cell value depending other cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

Hı all,

I am trying to figure out how I can put a formule to do this.
    Cell a  quantity
    Cell b  unit
    Cell c  unit price 
    Cell d   unit of cell b. 
So
    Cell a.   Cell b.    Cell c.   Cell d.    Cell e
    100.       gram.     200.       kg.          20
   If in cell b is gram chosen and cell d is.     kg then cell e must be cell c isdeviced by 1000 multiplied withcell a
 I have the formule in Excel, but want to put it in vba. Is more secure for accidents like deleting.

This is the code I have and works well.
How can I put this in the vba editor?

```
=(IF(B4="Gr",(A4*1),IF(B4="Ml",
   (A4*1),IF(B4="Paket",
 (A4*D4),IF(B4="Yk",
 (A4*12),IF(B4="Ck",
 (A4*8),IF(B4="Adet",(A4*1),
 IF(B4="Kg",(A4*1000),IF(B4="Lt",
 (A4*1),IF(B4>7,""))))))))*D4))


=IF(G10="Gr", ((F10*1)*E10),
IF(G10="Ml",((F10/16)*E10),
IF(G10="Paket",(F10*E10),
IF(G10="Yk",((F10/32)*E10),
IF(G10="Ck",((F10/128)*E10),
IF(G10="Adet",((F10*1)*E10),
IF(G10="Kg",((F10/1000)*E10),
IF(G10="Lt",((F10/1000)*E10),
IF(G10="","0")))))))))
```

Comment: I have it in the cells. But sometimes accidents happen and i delete the formule. It s safer with vba I think

Comment: You can do something like `Range("H10").formula = "=YOUR FUNCTION"`

Comment: You can protect cells which contain a formula to guard against accidental deletion. If you want to go the VBA route, it would make more sense to throw the formula away and create an equivalent but more readable VBA function. The chief advantage of VBA is that it allows you to clearly spell out the logic of a computation without needing to use deeply nested, not very readable worksheet formulas. Why pass up on the chief advantage of VBA? Protection against accidental deletion doesn't seem like an adequate motivation IMHO.

Comment: I ve tried for 2 day's now. Yes I want the same calculation but in vba. But how hard I search, I can t find anything.

Comment: I've tried if else statement with conditions. How much I try, how messy it becomes. So asked for help o you guy's

Comment: What value if false do you have for `IF(B4>7,"")` at the end of the first formula?

Comment: I don't know. I don't get an error. I just changed the formula to my needs.

Comment: As a side note on formulae like this, I would advise use of the new Excel function `IFS` to replace all those nested IF functions. It's not backwards compatible (only 2016 onwards has the formula, and only with a 365 subscription, or Excel online) - but if you have it, I'd recommend it as it is much more readable.

Answer (score 1):

The VBA function `IIf` is the function which directly corresponds to the worksheet function `IF`. Thus if you want a literal VBA transcription of those exact formulas it would look something like this:

```
Function FirstFormula() As Variant
    FirstFormula = (IIf(Range("B4").Value = "Gr", (Range("A4").Value * 1), IIf(Range("B4").Value = "Ml", _
        (Range("A4").Value * 1), IIf(Range("B4").Value = "Paket", _
        (Range("A4").Value * Range("D4").Value), IIf(Range("B4").Value = "Yk", _
        (Range("A4").Value * 12), IIf(Range("B4").Value = "Ck", _
        (Range("A4").Value * 8), IIf(Range("B4").Value = "Adet", (Range("A4").Value * 1), _
        IIf(Range("B4").Value = "Kg", (Range("A4").Value * 1000), IIf(Range("B4").Value = "Lt", _
        (Range("A4").Value * 1), IIf(Range("B4").Value > 7, "", False)))))))) * Range("D4").Value))
End Function    

Function SecondFormula() As Variant
    SecondFormula = IIf(Range("G10").Value = "Gr", ((Range("F10").Value * 1) * Range("E10").Value), _
        IIf(Range("G10").Value = "Ml", ((Range("F10").Value / 16) * Range("E10").Value), _
        IIf(Range("G10").Value = "Paket", (Range("F10").Value * Range("E10").Value), _
        IIf(Range("G10").Value = "Yk", ((Range("F10").Value / 32) * Range("E10").Value), _
        IIf(Range("G10").Value = "Ck", ((Range("F10").Value / 128) * Range("E10").Value), _
        IIf(Range("G10").Value = "Adet", ((Range("F10").Value * 1) * Range("E10").Value), _
        IIf(Range("G10").Value = "Kg", ((Range("F10").Value / 1000) * Range("E10").Value), _
        IIf(Range("G10").Value = "Lt", ((Range("F10").Value / 1000) * Range("E10").Value), _
        IIf(Range("G10").Value = "", "0", False)))))))))
End Function
```

Putting `=FirstFormula()` in a cell should be functionally equivalent to placing that exact formula in the cell, and similarly for the second formula. Note if you go this route, then the references to the formula don't automatically update when you copy the formula down, the cell references "B4", etc. are hard-wired into it.

I haven't tested the above, but it compiles nicely and it follows your logic exactly. If it doesn't suit your needs, consider using the excellent suggestion of @VBAPete.

**On Edit** Here is a more flexible version:

```
Function FirstFormula(A As Range, B As Range, D As Range) As Variant
    FirstFormula = (IIf(B.Value = "Gr", (A.Value * 1), IIf(B.Value = "Ml", _
        (A.Value * 1), IIf(B.Value = "Paket", _
        (A.Value * D.Value), IIf(B.Value = "Yk", _
        (A.Value * 12), IIf(B.Value = "Ck", _
        (A.Value * 8), IIf(B.Value = "Adet", (A.Value * 1), _
        IIf(B.Value = "Kg", (A.Value * 1000), IIf(B.Value = "Lt", _
        (A.Value * 1), IIf(B.Value > 7, "", False)))))))) * D.Value))
End Function


Function SecondFormula(E As Range, F As Range, G As Range) As Variant
    SecondFormula = IIf(G.Value = "Gr", ((F.Value * 1) * E.Value), _
        IIf(G.Value = "Ml", ((F.Value / 16) * E.Value), _
        IIf(G.Value = "Paket", (F.Value * E.Value), _
        IIf(G.Value = "Yk", ((F.Value / 32) * E.Value), _
        IIf(G.Value = "Ck", ((F.Value / 128) * E.Value), _
        IIf(G.Value = "Adet", ((F.Value * 1) * E.Value), _
        IIf(G.Value = "Kg", ((F.Value / 1000) * E.Value), _
        IIf(G.Value = "Lt", ((F.Value / 1000) * E.Value), _
        IIf(G.Value = "", "0", False)))))))))
End Function
```

Then in a worksheet, for example, you could use

```
=FirstFormula(A4,B4,D4)
```

and it will be equivalent. Furthermore, the references to `A4`, `B4`, `D4` would update as expected when the formula is copied down a range.

**On Further Edit** If you want to pursue the idea of using VBA to *insert* the formulas directly in a cell, you would use something like:

```
Dim form As String
form = "=IF(G10=""Gr"", ((F10*1)*E10),"
form = form & "IF(G10=""Ml"",((F10/16)*E10),"
form = form & "IF(G10=""Paket"",(F10*E10),"
form = form & "IF(G10=""Yk"",((F10/32)*E10),"
form = form & "IF(G10=""Ck"",((F10/128)*E10),"
form = form & "IF(G10=""Adet"",((F10*1)*E10),"
form = form & "IF(G10=""Kg"",((F10/1000)*E10),"
form = form & "IF(G10=""Lt"",((F10/1000)*E10),"
form = form & "IF(G10="""",""0"")))))))))"

Range("H10").Formula = form
```

In the above I built up the formula string in stages in the interest of readability. You don't need to do that, but the result would be, well, less readable.

Not that if you want quote marks to appear *inside* a string you have to double them up (use `""` rather than `"`) so that VBA can tell that the overall string isn't supposed to end there.

Comment: Thank you very much. I ll try the suggestions when I get home. Can I use a dynamic range in place of referring to a cell?

Comment: @Erol with my approach you would need to do something like use offsets from `Application.Caller` (the cell that contains the formula). A more straight-forward idea is to make the function take arguments, so that things like `G10` wouldn't be hard-wired but instead would be passed to the function. You would then enter these cells into the formula by clicking on them. I'll edit my question to show how this works.

Comment: The circular reference isn't in the VBA -- it is in how you are using the formulas. You must have *formulas* in e.g. `A4` which depends on the cell (either directly or indirectly) that you have the formulas entered in.

Comment: Range("H10").formula = "=(IF(B4="Gr",(A4*1),IF(B4="Ml",
   (A4*1),IF(B4="Paket",
 (A4*D4),IF(B4="Yk",
 (A4*12),IF(B4="Ck",
 (A4*8),IF(B4="Adet",(A4*1),
 IF(B4="Kg",(A4*1000),IF(B4="Lt",
 (A4*1),IF(B4>7,""))))))))*D4))"   this one gave me the error.

Comment: That looks like some VBA you were using to try to implement @VBAPete's idea. If so, that won't work like that since 1) you have a stray = in `==` and 2) you are not escaping the quote marks.